# JavaScript - NaN wierdness

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```
console.log(
                "r=" + r + "; " +
                "a=" + a + "; " +
                "cx=" + cx + "; " +
                "Math.cos(a)=" + Math.cos(a) + "; " +
                "r * Math.cos(a)=" + (r * Math.cos(a)) + "; " +
                "cx.x + r * Math.cos(a)=" + (cx.x + r * Math.cos(a)) + "; "
            );
```

Result:

```
r=0; a=0; cx=451; Math.cos(a)=1; r * Math.cos(a)=0; cx.x + r * Math.cos(a)=NaN;
```

NaNs are NaN for all values of r and a, just didn't want to post redundant results.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: If the ouput isn't a number, whatever you're putting in probably isn't a number either ?

Comment: What is `cx.x`? In the other line you are using `cx`.

Comment: `console.log(typeof cx)`. You are showing the value of `cx`, but in the addition you are using `cx.x`.

Comment: What type is `cx`? Does it have a property called `x`? That would be my first guess, as your `r` and `a` variables are clearly numbers. `cx=451` makes me suspicious, if `cx` was an object with an `x` property, the output of `cx` wouldn't be 451.

Comment: yes, that is what I missed. I went from using point to x and y and overlooked this change. Isn't this forum supposed to be the "rubber duck"? what's with the down votes? someone thinks there is such a thing as a "stupid question?"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trivial typo. It won't help anyone else.

Comment: Should I only ask questions that help other people? I thought I could ask for help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the output, `cx` seems to be a number which means `cx.x` will be `undefined`. So the last formula is `undefined + ...` which results in NaN when using JavaScripts strange rules (at least in the Chrome console):

```
> cx = 451;
451
> cx.x+1
NAN
```